# Task.ContinueWith doesn't work after previous Task completed

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

While i read `Jeffrey Richter, CLR via C#`, i've found this example. There are expected executing new Tasks depending on `TaskContinuationOptions`, but it isn't. I thought i would have next result:

```
Finished, SUM=5050
```

but i have empty output, even if i add `throw exception` in `Sum` function, `OnlyOnFaulted` wouldn't be executed.

```
class Program
{
    public static Int32 Sum(Int32 n)
    {
        Int32 Sum = 0;
        for (; n > 0; n--)
            Sum += n;

        return Sum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<Int32> t = new Task<Int32>(n => Sum((Int32)n), 100);

        t.ContinueWith(tt => Console.WriteLine("Finished, SUM={0}", tt.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        t.ContinueWith(tt => Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        t.Start();            
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you setup continuation correctly, but you can't see result on console, because application exists before:

```
Task<Int32> t = new Task<Int32>(n => Sum((Int32)n), 100);

t.ContinueWith(tt => Console.WriteLine("Finished, SUM={0}", tt.Result),
               TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
t.ContinueWith(tt => Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown"), 
               TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

t.Start();
Console.ReadKey(); // keep app alive
```

Application will not wait for background thread completion - it will be closed when main thread of application finishes it's work (your Main method)

**EDIT** Another option is to wait until backround thread (continuation thread) completes and keep application alive:

```
Task continuation = 
    t.ContinueWith(tt => Console.WriteLine("Finished, SUM={0}", tt.Result),
                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

t.Start();
continuation.Wait(); // wait until continuation of task finishes
// exit application
```

Comment: but if i add `t.Wait()`, application still finishes? Or it waits first completed task (`Sum`) and don't wait second (`WriteLine`)?

Comment: @FSou1 if you add `t.Wait()` it blocks main thread execution until task is completed. So that also keeps app alive, but with blocked main thread. I.e. id you have some code after `t.Wait()` it will not be executed until task completes.

Comment: Yeah, but why if i replace `Console.ReadKey();` with `t.Wait()` i shouldn't see my message? Looks like it have to finished each task before `t.Wait()` and display result?

Comment: @FSou1 you are waiting for task to complete, but then application exits, without waiting continuation to complete.